# Why must we use Base64 library in AES algorithms?

Tags: java, algorithm, encryption, base64

I'm writing a Java program to implements AES algorithms. I reviewed in many Java sites or forums about their code. 
 1. http://zenu.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/aes-128bit-cross-platform-java-and-c-encryption-compatibility/
 2. http://www.code2learn.com/2011/06/encryption-and-decryption-of-data-using.html
And I wonder why they always use Base64 library in their code. I think it will make our program (encrypted and decrypted) slower than when we don't use it.
Any one can be explain for me.

Answer (score 1):

Base64 is easier to read, check and transfer. e.g. email message with binary need Base64.

While Base64 is slower, it is trivial compared with encryption and decryption.

You don't have to use Base64, but I suggest you use it to start with and remove it when everything is working.